# I am trying to get Access Token for using Spotify API but get "error_description":"grant_type parameter is missing"

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, spotify

Using this instruction https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/ and converting it from js into python I get the {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant_type parameter is missing"}
Where is my mistake [image]

P.S. I found out how to get access_token after inspecting how it was implemented in spotipy lib [image]

Comment: you need a request body with `grant_type` of `client_credentials`

Comment: Yep, it really required field "grant_type" that doesn't wrapped in "form" as was written in documentation. But now i got "invalid_client". Let's inquire this problem